# Access and loop through a JSON file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

It's about [basil.js](http://basiljs.ch/). I try to get the data out of a JSON file. The file  `data.json` looks like this:

```
   {
      "user":"Hayyim",
      "datum":"12. April",
      "content":"# indien # wahlen",
      "sharedcontent":"nzz.chIndien: Gr\u00f6sste Wahl der Welt - logistische HerausforderungIn Indien beginnt am Donnerstag die Parlamentswahl. Sie dauert sechs Wochen. Es gibt 900 Millionen Stimmberechtigte und 11 Millionen Wahlhelfer.",
      "sharedimage":"https:\/\/external-frx5-1.xx.fbcdn.net\/safe_image.php?d=AQCVZce1YnnCI32G&amp;w=540&amp;h=282&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fimg.nzz.ch%2FC%3DW5760%2CH3024%2CX0%2CY408%2FS%3DW1200M%2CH630M%2FO%3D75%2FC%3DAR1200x630%2Fhttps%3A%2F%2Fnzz-img.s3.amazonaws.com%2F2019%2F4%2F10%2Fc0967283-706b-4254-88b4-4bd1e994e8ef.jpeg%3Fwmark%3Dnzz&amp;cfs=1&amp;upscale=1&amp;fallback=news_d_placeholder_publisher&amp;_nc_hash=AQAyTO8QmCpcQpvk",
      "comments":[

      ]
   },
   {
      "user":"Hayyim",
      "datum":"11. April",
      "content":"# israel # wahlen",
      "sharedcontent":"faz.net| Von FAZ.NET - Frankfurter Allgemeine ZeitungNetanjahu-Herausforderer: Gantz gibt sich geschlagenErst feierte er sich noch als Sieger, nun hat Netanjahus Herausforderer Benny Gantz eingesehen, dass er die Parlamentswahl in Israel verloren hat. Nun beginnen die Koalitionsgespr\u00e4che.",
      "sharedimage":"https:\/\/external-frx5-1.xx.fbcdn.net\/safe_image.php?d=AQAFQY0fbKU3hH9H&amp;w=540&amp;h=282&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedia1.faz.net%2Fppmedia%2Faktuell%2F1514615769%2F1.6134923%2Farticle_multimedia_overview%2Fhat-seine-niederlage.jpg&amp;cfs=1&amp;upscale=1&amp;fallback=news_d_placeholder_publisher&amp;_nc_hash=AQCGbgGQxkt-pZra",
      "comments":[
         {
            "comment":"https:\/\/www.akweb.de\/ak_s\/ak588\/30.htm",
            "comment_user":"Hayyim"
         }
      ]
   },
```

I access or load the JSON file in a javascript using this:

```
var json_file = b.loadString('data.json');
var obj = b.JSON.decode(json_file);
```

Then, I would like to create a loop that loops through the JSON file and returns the following using `b.text()`:

```
11. April
# israel # wahlen
faz.net| Von FAZ.NET - Frankfurter Allgemeine ZeitungNetanjahu-Herausforderer: Gantz gibt sich geschlagenErst feierte er sich noch als Sieger, nun hat Netanjahus Herausforderer Benny Gantz eingesehen, dass er die Parlamentswahl in Israel verloren hat. Nun beginnen die Koalitionsgespr\u00e4che.
https:\/\/www.akweb.de\/ak_s\/ak588\/30.htm
```

Then returning the next object.

Also, I would like to return the image (`"sharedimage"`) as an actual image, using `b.image()`.

I looked [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp), but couldn't figure it out. Please ask if the question is unclear.

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish here?  What do you want the output to be?

Comment: I don't realy understand your probleme but, if you have the file then use `fs` to read it or `fs-extra` that has `fs.readJSON()` and that will return an object/array from the JSON. (You can even use `require(..path..)` that will also read the JSON but then you will need to use `JSON.parse(require(..path..)))`.

Comment: The output should be the value of `"datum"`, then of `"content"`, then of `"sharedcontent"`, using `b.text()`. Then, the image should be outputed using `b.image()`. Then going to the next object.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var json_file = b.loadString('data.json');
var obj = JSON.parse(json_file);

for(let item of obj) {
    console.log(item.user);
    console.log(item.datum);
    .....
}
```

Here I suppose that `b.loadString` have actually loaded your json file

PS: note that the `comments` property is an array so you will have to loop through it if you want to access each child item

Comment: Thank you. Yes, `b.loadString` has loaded the JSON file. As you can see in the code snippet above, there are multiple objects. The object should be outputed just like you did. Then the next object should be outputed. How do I do this? (I can't try it out right now, I'm sorry.)

Comment: @VHS obj contains all the json file data. So the for loop will give you each object one by one. The first `item.user` will print `Hayyim`, the second will print `Hayyim` and so on...

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much!